# Как получить movies из объекта?

Tags: javascript, объекты

есть бд в формате JSON. Мне необходимо получить уникальные movies по всем героям.

Как это сделать?

```
[
  {
    "name": "Ancient One",
    "species": "human",
    "gender": "Female",
    "birthDay": "1316",
    "deathDay": "2017",
    "status": "deceased",
    "actors": "Tilda Swinton",
    "photo": "dbimage/DS_Ancient_One_Poster_cropped.png",
    "movies": [
      "Doctor Strange",
      "Avengers: Endgame"
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "Ant-Man",
    "realName": "Scott Edward Harris Lang",
    "species": "human",
    "citizenship": "American",
    "gender": "male",
    "status": "alive",
    "actors": "Paul Rudd",
    "photo": "dbimage/AntMan-EndgameProfile.jpg",
    "movies": [
      "Ant-Man",
      "Captain America: Civil War",
      "Ant-Man and the Wasp",
      "Avengers: Endgame"
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "Black Panther",
    "realName": "T'Challa",
    "species": "human",
    "citizenship": "Wakandan",
    "gender": "male",
    "status": "alive",
    "actors": "Chadwick Boseman",
    "photo": "dbimage/Black_Panther_AIW_Profile.jpg",
    "movies": [
      "Captain America: Civil War",
      "Black Panther",
      "Avengers: Infinity War",
      "Avengers: Endgame"
    ]
  },
]
```

Comment: что значит _уникальные movies по всем героям_? Какой именно результат ты ожидаешь для приведенного массива?

Comment: в movies есть повторяющиеся фильмы, мне нужно получить только уникальные значения movies, т.е массив с уникальными значениями movies

Comment: Приведите пример конечного результата относительно исходных данных из вопроса.

Comment: Получите массив всех героев и оставьте уникальных new Set([arr]) https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set

Answer (score 0):

Получите массив всех героев и оставьте уникальных new Set([arr])

```js
const heros = [
  {
    "name": "Ancient One",
    "species": "human",
    "gender": "Female",
    "birthDay": "1316",
    "deathDay": "2017",
    "status": "deceased",
    "actors": "Tilda Swinton",
    "photo": "dbimage/DS_Ancient_One_Poster_cropped.png",
    "movies": [
      "Doctor Strange",
      "Avengers: Endgame"
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "Ant-Man",
    "realName": "Scott Edward Harris Lang",
    "species": "human",
    "citizenship": "American",
    "gender": "male",
    "status": "alive",
    "actors": "Paul Rudd",
    "photo": "dbimage/AntMan-EndgameProfile.jpg",
    "movies": [
      "Ant-Man",
      "Captain America: Civil War",
      "Ant-Man and the Wasp",
      "Avengers: Endgame"
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "Black Panther",
    "realName": "T'Challa",
    "species": "human",
    "citizenship": "Wakandan",
    "gender": "male",
    "status": "alive",
    "actors": "Chadwick Boseman",
    "photo": "dbimage/Black_Panther_AIW_Profile.jpg",
    "movies": [
      "Captain America: Civil War",
      "Black Panther",
      "Avengers: Infinity War",
      "Avengers: Endgame"
    ]
  },
]

const movies = heros.map( hero => hero.movies).reduce( (summ, el) => [...summ, ...el])

const uniqHeroes = new Set(movies)

console.log(uniqHeroes)
```

Вариант с flatMap:

```js
const movies = heros.flatMap( hero => hero.movies)

const uniqHeroes = new Set(movies)

console.log(uniqHeroes)
```

Comment: вместо map.reduce можно [flatMap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap)

Comment: Спасибо, добавил вариант

Comment: а зачем `[...hero.movies]`?

Comment: Поправил, раньше не пользовался flatMap )